# how to deduplicate data sent over remote_write from multiple Prometheus instances scraping the same target

Tags: prometheus

I'm new to Prometheus and I'm wondering what the best practice for remote_write is when it comes to a Prometheus deployment that is federated or having multiple Prometheus servers scraping the same target as a way to prevent data loss when 1 server goes down.

Since with the brute force approach, If I set up remote_write on all of the Prometheus servers (or a couple of those where data is aggregated), then I would be getting tons of duplicated data... so is it designed that data deduplication should be handled by the 3rd party storage system (that seems to be a hard problem considering the amount of data being sent, frequency, slight time offset and efficiency)? or am I missing something here?

In the federated case, I assume that I can just set up remote_write on the server that scrapes all the data from other Prometheus server (but still what if there are multiple of them, though I don't know if this is a valid deployment scenario).

Comment: There is this: https://blog.timescale.com/blog/prometheus-ha-postgresql-8de68d19b6f5/ It seems to only take data from one of multiple identical sources into the remote_write store...

Comment: Cortex looks like it is designed for exactly this use case: https://cortexmetrics.io/docs/architecture/ The HA tracker would do the deduplication

Comment: Cortex or thanos is what we used in our project.